# preg_replace how to do that?

Tags: php

So I occured one problem. I got a code -

```
[caption id="attachment222" align="aligncenter" width="520" caption="caption ghoes here"]<img class="image-caption" title="title" src="picture link goes here" alt="" width="520" height="328" />[/caption]
```

So basically what I need to do is go through $content, get each `<img>` src that is inside [caption][/caption] tags, for more info, see the code above, and insert the src link inside caption and remove the img tag, so in the end it would look like `[caption id="attachment222" align="aligncenter" width="520" caption="caption ghoes here" url="picture link goes here"][/caption]` .

AS you can see, the src is changed to url too. Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Sounds like somebody needs to learn regular expressions! +1 @anubhava for DOM

Comment: @anubhava this works perfectly fine with a RegEx. DOM is too clunky for this.. I doubt it would even work well, as the elements in brackets will most likely not end up as DOM nodes at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$parsed = preg_replace(
    '{\[caption([^\]]+)\]<img.*?src=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?/>}mi',
    '[caption$1 url="$2"]',
    $sourceText
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm, I think it's time for me to start learning regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exact, but it will point you in the right direction.

Using a regexpression like this will do 2 things get your caption data, and your image src

```
[caption (.*)]<img class="image-caption" title="title" src="(.*)" alt="" width="520" height="328" />[/caption]
```

Then you use it in preg_replace with this.

```
[caption $1 src="$2"][/caption]
```

$1 is the content in (.*) of your caption and $2 is the image src.  If the title and other attributes in the [img] tag are dynamic then simply replace them in the reg express with .* like so.

```
[caption (.*)]<img class=".*" title=".*" src="(.*)" alt=".*" width=".*" height=".*" />[/caption]
```

That should work.  (I suck at regular expressions, so there may be a more elegant way).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex might be something like `#<img.*?/>#i`.  I'll let you figure out the rest.